# How to remove the /snap directory?

Tags: permissions, filesystems, rm

I want to remove the snap directory:

```
sudo rm -rfv   /snap
rm: cannot remove '/snap/*': Read-only file system
```

Remount it as read and write.

```
df  /snap
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda4      127337732 43495868  77330352  36% /
sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda4
```

Have a try again:

```
sudo rm -rfv   /snap
```

Same error:

```
rm: cannot remove '/snap/*': Read-only file system
```

I am using debian, i prefer debian to ubuntu,want to remove it permanently.

Answer (score 1):

This folder is used Live Patch updates and should not be deleted.

Please see:  [Canonical's Snaps](https://hackernoon.com/managing-ubuntu-snaps-the-stuff-no-one-tells-you-625dfbe4b26c)

> Canonical's Snaps are definitely the real deal. The secure and
> portable Linux package management system is more than a geeky tool for
> showing off your tech creds. Just consider the growing list of
> companies that have already bought in and are providing their desktop
> software through snaps, including Blender, Slack, Spotify, Android
> Studio, and Microsoft’s (Microsoft!) Visual Studio Code.